# Redirecting one URL with querystring to another URL with querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect a URL with a querystring to another URL which also has a querystring.

How would I redirect the URL `/opinion/feature.php?id=97` to `/article/article.php?id=1494`?

Answer (score 0):

In General you dont need to specify anything to append the querystring.

Following should work

```
Keep original query (default behavior)
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /target.php [L]
# from http://example.com/page.php?foo=bar
# to   http://example.com/target.php?foo=bar
```

Comment: I tried the following but it doesn't work for me

RewriteRule ^opinion/feature\.php?id=97$ /article/article.php?id=1490 [L]

Answer (score 0):

```
# Turn ON RewriteEngine 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/opinion/feature.php(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/article/article.php$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

**Edit after user comments:**
If you have only 1 URL to be redirected, with fix ID values you mentioned, you can use below:

```
# Turn ON RewriteEngine 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/opinion/feature.php\?id=97$ http://www.yourdomain.com/article/article.php\?id=1494 [NE,L,R=301]
```

If you have multiple similar URL (with relatively less numbers and you know both corresponding IDs) you can put similarly here, otherwise it would be better to handle PHP to redirect based on two id mapping through `header()` function

Comment: It works fine if both source and target IDs are same but it doesn't work for different IDs.

/opinion/feature.php?id=97 Here ID is 97 and
/article/article.php?id=1494 Here ID is 1494

Comment: Hi Minesh. Thanks for your reply.
The RewriteRule given by you doesn't work. I've 500 records which need redirection this way. Is there any way of calling an external file within .htaccess? The file may contain the mapping IDs which will be called within the .htaccess code. Is there any such way of doing this?